# How can I check if the computer is a Surface Studio?

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing an app specifically for Surface Studio - how is it possible to check that the machine is indeed a Surface Studio?

Ideally from within .NET, although perhaps this is information gleaned from the registry, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can get more info about it by using [Win32 Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx), it will help you a lot querying almost everything about your system.

To be easier, you can also [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) an application provided by Microsoft which allows you to better search the info you are looking for. The information you are looking for is probably located at `Win32_ComputerSystem`.

Comment: While (after a quick check) I'm certain the information will be burried somewhere within the linked functionality, it's not really trivial to find immediately. So in case you know a little more specific which of the Win32 Classes would provide the information, please add this to the answer.

Comment: Already updated it. I did an application based on this Microsoft application and it helps a lot. @grek40

Comment: Did you get something from there? Or you need something else? @grek40

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I think it points me in the right direction but it's difficult to work out what to query for this information. The exe in the package didn't run, and when I put the code for the exe into a new application it runs, but any queries to WMI end with "generic failure". I am running in admin mode, not sure where to go from here!

Comment: @Rekcs I don't really need this, I'm just telling you that the answer is sort of incomplete as long as it doesn't mention a specific solution how to get the asked information. It has useful links, but it's not complete answer in itself.

Comment: It's difficult because it has a lot of information and you have to search until you find what you want. If you want I can update de question with an example where it might be. @joshcomley

Comment: Update: actually it is only hardware queries that fail. I have looked at `root\CIMV2\Win32_ComputerSystem\Model`, perhaps this is useful.

Comment: In my case the model is located in `root\CIMV2\Win32_ComputerSystem\Model`. Do you want me to update the question with a code? @joshcomley

Comment: Is this information possible to "fake"? Is it possible to trick my development laptop for example into returning a different model? i.e. is this foolproof :) I guess it comes from the BIOS, somehow, for model etc., in which case it should be pretty solid

Comment: I don't thing so. Everything I used there to develop my application worked fine and I checked if the information is true. @joshcomley

Comment: @joshcomley are you concerned about setting up a testing environment (wanted: trick the dev) or about security (wanted: hard block any non-surface; paranoid: block surface emulators (not that I think it's possible or should be done))